# How to get a BDC or XML file from SQL Server to use for BDC in SharePoint?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2007, bdc

I have a simple database for a stack management system. I want to use this database in SharePoint. So I need to use the [BDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563661%28v=office.12%29.aspx) concept in SharePoint services, right? How can I generate the required form for BDC of database in my SQL Server 2008? I have installed SharePoint with [MOSS 2007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint_Server#MOSS_2007).

What steps do I have to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BDC Meta Man to create an application definition file.

[BDC Meta-man](http://www.lightningtools.com/bdc-meta-man/default.aspx).

Comment: any other option which will free source ?

Comment: Not it is the trail version. I have downloaded, If have some link from that i can download full version free.please send me.

Comment: best would be to write a mail to contact@lightningtools.com